# Estimating torque between two states?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, torque, complex-numbers

Given an object whose orientation is given by a quaternion $q_1$, what constant torque must be applied over a time Δt in order to achieve a desired orientation $q_2$ ?

Note: $q_1$, $q_2$, Δt, inertial matrix,mass and angular velocities for $q_1$ and $q_2$ are known.

Comment: I think this is a surprisingly difficult problem. See [this paper from NASA](https://engineering.purdue.edu/people/james.m.longuski.1/ConferencePapersPresentations/1980SolutionofEulersEquationsofMotionandEulerianAnglesforNearSymmetricRigidBodiesSubjecttoConstantMoments.pdf) to understand the complexity of motion of a body under constant troque.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. This is the subject of many books (search for "attitude control" at books.google.com). There many books just on the subject of spacecraft attitude control, one of which is [Spacecraft Attitude Determination and Control by James Wertz](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=crTwCAAAQBAJ).

Comment: As the above comments state, the general solution you are asking for could fill a book. Would you be happy with a solution to a simpler problem? Otherwise I agree with @DavidHammen that this is "too broad" for this forum.

Comment: Well apart from the maths, doesn't torque result in angular acceleration. You'ld have to apply an equal and opposite torque to stop turning. Not clear why do you think a constant torque will give a solution?

Comment: Please show your attempt to solve this problem, and state what conceptual difficulty you are having.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining the torque needed to rotate a spacecraft to a given rotation/quaternion](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/317615) posted by the same user. **Please do not post the same question more than once.** If you are not satisfied with the answers provided, make an edit to your question, this will bring it back to the attention of the community.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining the torque needed to rotate a spacecraft to a given rotation/quaternion](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/317615/determining-the-torque-needed-to-rotate-a-spacecraft-to-a-given-rotation-quatern)